# How to sort IQueryable<string> using odata?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, odata, asp.net-web-api

I have a web api that returns IQueryable i want to sort the list of string in asc order

My MyAPIController code

```
[Queryable]
    public IQueryable<string> Get()
    {

     //result
        return result.AsQueryable();
    }
```

I tried to cal using

> http://www.ServerAddress.com/api/MyAPI?$orderby

But it is giving HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request error.
what is the right syntax for sorting?

Answer (score 0):

The sort Url should be:
http://www.ServerAddress.com/api/EntitySetName?$orderby=PropertyName asc

Answer (score 0):

The OData 3 syntax would be:

```
?$orderby=$it asc
```